# How can I use mobile native controls using React-Select in a React Web App?

Tags: reactjs, input, react-select

I'm using the library [React-Select](https://react-select.com/) in my react app for various input fields (selects, dropdown, datepicker, etc.)

Normally an input type will trigger the native controls on a mobile devices (ie datepicker will bring up the ios/android datepicker and a select will open up the scrollview for options), however with react-select this isn't the case.

Is there an option to default to the native mobile input controls using react-select?  If so, how? And if not, what are the other potential options.